# xsl:include of another xslt file from Win32 resources

Tags: c++, xslt, resources

I'm using xslt transformer in my C++ Win32 application and several xsl files that have a common part that I would like to separate into another xsl file. All xsl files are stored as resources. The only way I encountered for xsl:include is using res:// protocol that does not work properly for xsl files (at least on two of my Windows installations loading of resulting xslt file returned an error and on one installation it worked allright). 
MSDN also mentions about the problem: http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B220830&x=13&y=12

Do I have any other options except:

1. Implementing my own protocol handler for loading included xsl files - does not worth doing.
2. Avoiding <xsl:include> and substituting included files myself - too clumsy.
3. Duplication of common part in all templates - no, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Two other xml/xslt libraries are Xerces (http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ - there's also a java flavour IIRC) and libxml (http://xmlsoft.org/). I started with Xerces and ended up using libxml (both with C++), but I don't really like either of them: neither seems to correspond to my perception of what needs to be done - perhaps my failing. I found libxml more hackable though.

Also, I used these with VC6, but I don't think your version would kick up about them.